# Momentjs - cannot set hour and minutes in UTC

Tags: momentjs

Why

```
moment().utc("14:30", "HH:mm").format()
```

gives me

2019-06-07T00:56:14Z - my local time

instead of

2019-06-07T14:30:14Z

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the moment without `()` like this `moment.utc("14:30", "HH:mm").format()`

Comment: Thank you. No longer, I don't have to split "hh:mm" for hours and minutes to make it works.
`moment().utc().hour("14").minute("30").format()`.